# how to plot an RDF graph for inspection?

Tags: macos, debugging, rdf, plot

The W3 has a RDF validator that plots the RDF graph. Do you know a similar utility desktop side ?

Forgot to say. I'm on a mac.

Answer (score 7):

For example, [raptor](http://www.librdf.org/raptor/) has the rapper command line utility that can parse various RDF syntaxes and output DOT to be plotted with [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/).

(Disclosure: I'm a committer in the raptor project.)

Answer (score 2):

+1 for using Raptor and Graphviz. Here's how to do it one go (assuming that your RDF is in Turtle syntax):

```
rapper -i turtle -o dot rdf.ttl | dot -Tpdf -ograph.pdf
```

The output is written to graph.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Like laalto said GraphViz is the typical thing to use and many RDF APIs have support built in for generating DOT to be plotted with ut

For example the API I develop ([dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/)) has a [GraphVizWriter](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/index.asp?Topic=VDS.RDF.Writing.GraphVizWriter) class that you can use to generate DOT files which you can then turn into images in your desired format with the dot.exe command line utility which is part of GraphViz

Though seeing as you're on a Mac my API is probably not much use to you personally - but regardless GraphViz is definitely the way to go.